# lightning:outputField only if field has value

Tags: lightning-aura-components

```
<lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{!v.recordId}" objectApiName="MyObject__c">
    <lightning:outputField fieldName="MyField__c"/>
</lightning:recordViewForm>
```

Let's say that `MyField__c` has `null` value (or whitespace or empty string), so instead I'd like to display a different field (possibly from a totally different object).
Is there a way to do that in markup?
I know I could use my JS controller to retrieve the record, check the fields and set an `aura:attribute` boolean flag. But if I have `recordViewForm` to do the heavy lifting for me, why should I have to query the DB myself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *really* easy way is to just do it in a formula field (`My_Formula_Field__c`) on `MyObject__c`:

```
IF(NOT(ISBLANK(MyField__c)), MyField__c, Some_Other_Field__c)
```

and

```
<lightning:outputField fieldName="My_Formula_Field__c"/>
```

That works if the other field you want to display is on the same object or is connected to it via a lookup relationship.

Alternately, you can use `<aura:if>` conditional logic inside `<lightning:recordViewForm>`, but you've got to independently get access to field values to do so (using, for example, `<force:recordData>`). Here's an example:

```
<aura:attribute name="fields" type="Object" />
<force:recordData aura:id="forceRecordCmp"
    recordId="{! v.recordId }"
    layoutType="FULL"
    fields="Name,Industry"
    mode="VIEW"
    targetFields="{!v.fields}"
    targetError="{!v.error}" />
<lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{! v.recordId }" objectApiName="Account">
    <aura:if isTrue="{! not(empty(v.fields.Industry)) }">
        <lightning:outputField fieldName="Industry"/>
        <aura:set attribute="else">
            <lightning:outputField fieldName="Name"/>
        </aura:set>
    </aura:if>
</lightning:recordViewForm>
```

Note that using conditional logic, the record view will show the label of whichever field is actually being displayed. Since that will change based on your logic, it may create some confusion for users. The value of the formula field solution is that you'll always show the label of the formula field.

If you want to substitute a value that involves more computation than can be achieved in a formula field, or needs a SOQL query to obtain, or don't want to apply an extra `<force:recordData>`, you'd have to write code to do that.